# Suspended platform hanger support spacing calculation

Tags: garage, woodworking, shelf

I am building a 8' x 4' storage shelf that I would like to hang from my ceiling. The frame of the shelf is constructed using 2" x 4". I have 2 x 4 cross supports every 24 inches. The shelf attached to the frame is a 1/2" OSB board.

Can someone help me determined how many hanging supports are needed to hang this from the ceiling. I am not sure of the calculation to figure this out. My plan is to suspend this with 3/8 threaded rod which will couple with a 3" lag screw. I would like to be able to support 600lbs.

Comment: Do you intend to have the 2x4's flat (wide face) to the OSB?

Comment: You did not tell us how your **ceiling is constructed**.

Comment: What is your ceiling constructed of? We need size and spacing and span. Is the ceiling material applied to the bottom of the floor joists? If so, what size spacing and span are they?

Answer (score 1):

You want to support the equivalent of 18.75 lbs per square foot which is a relatively a lot of load compared to what your ceiling is designed to support. You will need to reinforce your ceiling or provide an alternate support structure.

You need a minimum of (4) supports for it to be stable. Supports at each rafter or joist will spread the load better.

There is no hardware that couples threaded rod with a lag screw.

Comment: How do you know what the ceiling will support if you don’t know the span

Comment: @LeeSam how would the span affect the amount of square foot loading?

Comment: @LeeSam isn't the span somewhat irrelevant if the rafters/joists weren't designed to carry additional load? When we had joists built for our garage, we were asked if we were going to use it for storage and said yes. That changed the construction and price... I defer to you as you seem to have _far_ more engineering knowledge than I do, but if the roof wasn't designed for it, then it just wasn't designed for this kind of load, right?

Comment: @FreeMan Never assume what a roof, etc. will support. Yes, the Code mandates these systems support minimum loads, but without checking, how do you know? Ack’s statements like “18.75 psf which is a relatively lot of load compared to what your ceiling is designed to support “ is irresponsible without checking...and without knowing the span of the supports, you’re guessing. Ack’s statement “You will need to reinforce your ceiling or provide an alternate support structure” is meaningless until you KNOW what the ceiling can support AND you can’t determine that until you know the span.

Comment: Fair enough. You're the engineer (or more experienced with that realm than I am).

Comment: @LeeSam you're just simply wrong in several of your statements and further I can tell you're not an engineer what you say and how you say it. - Re "Ack’s statement “You will need to reinforce your ceiling or provide an alternate support structure” is meaningless until you KNOW what the ceiling can support AND you can’t determine that until you know the span" comes across as you simply out to bash me for who knows what reason (there is history here). My statement in effect says: Don't do it as it is. How do you find fault with that?

Comment: @Ack ...because you don’t know the resisting structural system. It might be perfectly fine. Before you make such an outlandish statement, why don’t you ask what is there, or don’t you know what to ask for to determine the strength of the existing system?

Comment: @LeeSam I agree with you that it can seem "outlandish" to those that don't have the knowledge to know better (and want to come across cantankerous). I don't ask those question because I don't need to. 18.75 psf is a lot even if it is floor above, in which case it's nearly 1/2 the design load (per code). I've shown why I can make my statement. Now you need to back up your statement...

Comment: @Ack You say you’ve “shown why you can make you statement”, but you haven’t. All you’ve done is say the load is “about half the design load (per code)”. Actually you made two errors in that statement: 1) the 40 psf required by code is just for Live Load...and you don’t know what the Dead Load is, and 2) you refer to floor loads...this is a ceiling. you haven’t shown any calculations because you don’t know what the structural system is. Anybody can say “it doesn’t work”. Show me it doesn’t work. You haven’t shown anything yet.

Comment: @LeeSam 1) I very reasonably assume that the design dead load is accurate therefore there is no additional capacity to be found there. You suggest using 47% of the design live load without protecting the area above with a placard or other means to make sure that will will be used only to it's reduced 53% live load rating (this isn't a thing you could do, even though you seem to advocate for it) 2) I went with floor above to be in YOUR favor. If roof trusses above then worst case it's designed for 10 psf. - re 
"Show me it doesn’t work." I didn't make that claim. What exactly is your issue?

Comment: @Ack What is my issue? I haven’t said it will work or it won’t work, because I don’t know what is there. I think you should admit you don’t know either.

Comment: @Ack Btw, how do you know the ceiling structure is connected to the floor above structure?

Comment: @LeeSam I gave an answer that is on a level matching the information provided, I answered the question as it was presented. re " how do you know the ceiling structure is connected to the floor above structure?" Do you even know what you are suggesting? What, a suspended ceiling? That won't help your argument much, would it? Even if it's a false ceiling for say a kitchen w/ a lower height, there is no live load capacity and this kills your argument. So what is your point here? You need to put yourself out there and post your own answer, you really haven't' said anything meaningful here.

Comment: Further, you feel a need to discuss further, go to the forums. Link it here so I am aware of it and I'll talk with you there